# Filter ObservableList item with a .class in a Controller

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to filter an ObservableList items to show only some of them in a TableView according to x rules. To do this I have a Database.class where are methods which filters data, but I don't know how can I use these methods in a Controller class.

Here is the .class

```
package es.upv.inf;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Database {

    private static Map<Product.Category, List<Product>> catalog;

    public Database() {
        //Compiled Code
    }

    public static List<Product> getProductByCategory(Product.Category cat) {
        //Compiled Code
    }

    public static List<Product> getProductByCategoryAndPrice(Product.Category cat, double minPrice, double maxPrice, boolean available) {
        //Compiled Code
    }

    public static List<Product> getProductByCategoryAndDescription(Product.Category cat, String substring, boolean available) {
        //Compiled Code
    }

    public static List<Product> getProductByCategoryDescriptionAndPrice(Product.Category cat, String substring, double minPrice, double maxPrice, boolean available) {
        //Compiled Code
    }
}
```

Comment: *Covert an ObservableList to List.* Why? It is already a `List` Please make it clearer what you want to achieve. This isn't enough code for me to understand what is going on.

Comment: @YassinHajaj the problem is now well specified?

Comment: Your database class doesn't really filter data; it provides it. Methods that filter data would take a list as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `setAll` on the observable list. You haven't provided any code, but you could call methods like

```
TableView<Product> table = new TableView<>();

// ...

table.getItems().setAll(Database.getProductByCategory(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Obseravble list to create a FilteredList, and install the FilteredList into the TableView via setItems().  Then you can manipulate the predicate property of the FilteredList and the table contents will change.